# bn256 and Boneh-Boyen digital signature in solidity

Tags: solidity, contract-design, contract-invocation, signature

I am looking to have a full-fledged implementation of bn256 in solidity. And  Boneh-Boyen digital signature. Is there is any available built-in libraries or implementation in solidity to bn256 and Boneh-Boyen digital signature?

Comment: What is bn256???

Comment: A BN-curve (Barreto-Naehrig curve) [paper] defines an elliptic curve which can be used for pairings that allow for a high security and efficiency level. This article uses pairings over a 256-bit BN curve and derives a signature for a message, and also outlines a method for where Bob, Alice and Carol can generate a shared key.https://medium.com/coinmonks/having-fun-with-bn-curves-37fb5b816f67

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this repo https://github.com/HarryR/solcrypto/ which includes some example how to use alt-bn256 primitives from solidity.